# Using environment variables in Node

Tags: node.js, git, environment-variables

I have been trying to get a streamline way of having different environment variables for local and production web apps, but I haven't come across the "ideal" solution yet.

There's the option of having a config.js file like so:

```
//config.js
{
    "secretKey": "SDFDASFFSFD",
    "facebook": {
        "clientID": "EFGFDGBGDGFS",
        "clientSecret": "EGDFNHFG"
    }
}
```

And accessing via ES6 imports

Or using .env files like so:

```
SOME_KEY=someValue
HELLO=world
FACEBOOK_SECRET=435SDFSF5DZVD7S
```

And accessing the variables via process.env in the code using dotenv.

Obviously no matter what route you go down, the file will need to be omitted from version control which is fine. Each of these ways are great, but they only seem to work well for local development.

So how do you then have a separate file for a production environment? The dotenv docs say they strongly recommend against a .local.env and .prod.env situation.

Also, how is best to push to a remote server? I have my own server with Gulp tasks which run on a Git post-receive hook. How is best to pass up the production environment variables to here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have own config file for each environment:

```
- environments
  - index.js
  - deveplopment.json
  - staging.json
  - production.json
```

To use appropriate config file, run the app with required `NODE_ENV`:

```
NODE_ENV=production node index
```

In `environments/index.js` determinate the current `NODE_ENV` and use config:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
module.exports = require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

If config file doesn't include secret info (apiKeys, etc), it can be pushed to repo. Otherwise add it to .gitignore and use environment variables on the server.

**Note:**

For advanced configuration use such packages as [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf).

> It allows to create hierarchical node.js configuration with files, environment variables, command-line arguments, and atomic object merging.

Comment: I see - this makes complete sense. The idea of my config files are that they do contain sensitive data, so what do you mean by using export variables? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I meant _environment variables_.

Comment: Ok, so how would you get the environment variables to the server?

Comment: You could read them via `process.env`: `$ MYVAR=somevalue node index`, then access it by its name: `console.log(process.env.MYVAR);`. Or use `nconf` module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about having a keys.js file with a .gitignore on it?

I've used this in the past to use module.exports{} to get my variables usable but not going to version control for the security side of things!

Comment: That's good for local development, but it's likely that the database credentials will be different between local and production versions of your code, so how do you push the production variables to the production system? Thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: You don't push them by the version control system, you edit the config file on the production server when you're deploying your app.