# Safely access secret keys in NodeJS CLI tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I have a NodeJS terminal utility that integrates with the Spotify API. The basic flow is:

- user launches cli tool in terminal
- CLI tool opens browser and completes oAuth 2.0 flow
- app stores access_token and refresh_token on user's filesystem.
- app uses credentials to get artwork for currently playing song and display it in the terminal

I have the actual app working, but currently it relies on a Spotify API `clientId` and `clientKey`, and Spotify docs recommend keeping that `clientKey` a secret.

Obviously I don't want each user to have to register their open app on spotify to use the utility.

Is there a secure way to store my `clientKey` that would allow a user to just

`npm install <utility>`

and then run?

Comment: Best bet is an environment variable (IMO), maybe see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717379/using-environment-variables-in-node

Comment: since this app has to be distributed through npm,storing keys somewhere in source code or in a package is not the best approach. In this case everybody could access your secret and use it. I suggest to use some remote server that responds with all required information (keys and so on) and protect this endpoint with Spotify access_tokens.

Comment: I think that's the problem - I thought about a remote server but I need the Spotify `clientId` and `clientSecret` to authenticate with Spotify to get the `access_token` in the first place. I could set up a separate db with users who register through the terminal, but that's a lot more work